# <textarea onclick="this.value; this.select();"> ? What kind of trick is this?

Tags: javascript, html

Working with somebody's code, I saw this:

```
<textarea onclick="this.value; this.select();">(Some predefined stuff)</textarea>
```

What kind of trick / hack is that and what it is supposed to do?

Comment: `this.value;` is useless. `this.select()` ... selects the content.

Comment: Can you post it as answer please?

Comment: and "content" means the textarea-content

Comment: You might want to check any checkin logs for that source file to see if that code looked different at some point in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement

```
this.value;
```

will have no effect. The following statement:

```
this.select();
```

will cause the contents of the `<textarea>` to be selected.

Comment: What I initially thought of was kind of dirty CSS / JS trick to avoid some weird effects on IE 8 or stuff... you all programmer folks will know what I mean. But `this.value` seems to be some random rubbish. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @BarthZalewski yes I know what you mean, but in this case I doubt it has any effect anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.value;
```

Will give the value but in the above mentioned code there will be no effect 
try

```
<textarea onclick="alert(this.value)">(Some predefined stuff)</textarea>

this.select();
```

when you click on the textbox the predefined text will be selected in blue color .

Comment: Sorry but how does your answer differs from the one which @poitny posted? how does posting the same answer helps ?

Comment: I perfectly know what `this.value` does, the problem was just to recognize if this is any trick for old browsers.